# How to make a line break on . notation in accordance to PEP8

Tags: python-3.x, formatting, pep8

So according to PEP8 a line in python shouldn't be any longer than 79 characters, and for some lines, only 72 characters. Now I've been running into this problem a lot lately, and normally it's not to hard to fix. For example say I have some code like this:

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, ...]
# Convert it to this (I'm too lazy to indent it sry)
x = [1,
2,
3,
4,
5,
6,
7,
8,
9,
1,
2,
3,
4,
5,
6,
7,
8,
9]
```

Now this isn't the problem. The problem arises when I have a . function.

For example this:

```
f'Some long f-string that's almost 79 characters...'.encode()
```

Now I could break the string but that makes it look very un clean, and hard to read, especially if it has embedded if or for statements in the f-string.

I've been doing this but I'm not sure if it's the right thing to do.

```
f'f-string that's long...'\
.encode()
```

So essentially I'm not sure if that's how to do it or I do something else.

Now also I've wondered how I'm supposed to properly indent strings that span multiple lines, because if I try and keep a common indentation, the string will get a huge indent.

For example:

```
x = '''Multi
       Line
       String'''

print(x)
```

Prints:

```
Multi
       Line
       String
```

So how do I format it so it looks nice, and works properly?

Comment: Check this, maybe it helps you: https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excerpt from [PEP-8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length) in Maximum Line Length:

> The preferred way of wrapping long lines is by using Python’s implied
> line continuation inside parentheses, brackets and braces. Long lines
> can be broken over multiple lines by wrapping expressions in
> parentheses. These should be used in preference to using a backslash
> for line continuation.

So following the suggestion, I would place the method call on the line following the f-string, and enclose the expression in parentheses:

```
s = (
    f"1 + 1 == {1 + 1}..."
    f'1 - 1 == {1 - 1}'
    .encode()
)
print(s)
```

This outputs:

```
b'1 + 1 == 2...1 - 1 == 0'
```

Regarding indenting a multi-line string represented in a triple-quoted docstring, you can follow the example shown in the documentation of [`textwrap.dedent`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.dedent) to indent all lines normally (but add a backslash after the first triple quote to avoid producing a newline character), and let `dedent` remove common leading spaces for you:

```
from textwrap import dedent

s = dedent('''\
    Multi
    Line
    String''')
print(s)
```

This outputs:

```
Multi
Line
String
```